# Taylor Series of a Complex Function

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis

Consider the function
$$
\exp\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right).
$$
Since this is holomorphic for $|z|<1$, then it has a Taylor Series valid for $|z|<1$, i.e.,
$$
\exp\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nz^n.
$$
What is $a_n$?

First I noticed that $a_0=1$. Then I used the definition of the exponential function to get
$$
\exp\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^n.
$$
Notice that 
$$
\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum^\infty_{r=0}z^r
$$
if $|z|<1$, then
$$
\exp\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\sum^\infty_{r=1}z^r\right)^n.
$$
First I noticed that only in the sums
$$
\sum^\infty_{r=1}z^r,\left(\sum^\infty_{r=1}z^r\right)^2,\dots,\left(\sum^\infty_{r=1}z^r\right)^n
$$
there exist a term of $z^n$. Then it remains to find the coefficients of $z^n$ in each of the following expression
$$
\left(\sum^\infty_{r=1}z^r\right)^s,s=1,2,\dots,n
$$
and sum then up from $1$ to $n$. Clearly the coefficient is $1$ for $s=1$. Then I got stuck. Could someone help me with this (actually a counting) problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
$$f(z):=\exp\left({z\over1-z}\right)$$
is the solution of the IVP
$$f'(z)={f(z)\over (1-z)^2},\qquad f(0)=1\ ,$$
or
$$f(z)-(1-z)^2 f'(z)=0, \qquad f(0)=1\ .$$
Now write $$f(z):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\>z^k$$
with undetermined coefficients $a_k$ and obtain a recursion formula for the $a_k$.

Answer (score 1):

Since:
$$\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^k = \sum_{n=k}^{+\infty}\binom{n-1}{k-1}z^n $$
we have:
$$\exp\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\binom{n-1}{k-1}z^n=1+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right)z^n$$
so:
$$[z^n]\exp\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\phantom{}_1 F_1(1-n;2;-1).$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: [Integer sequence A067764](https://oeis.org/A067764). (Not very satisfying, I guess, but I am not sure you will get a better description.)